# Is there an easy way to get water at roughly 70°C in our kitchen?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, water

Some green tea requires to pour water at 70°C. I have no thermal sensor or kettle with adjustable temperature with me.

Do you know a way to get water at roughly 70°C like “boil water and wait for *x* minutes” or “mix *x* part of boiling water with 1-*x* part of fresh water” ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Wait for $x$ minutes" is difficult because the cooling rate will depend on a lot of non-universal details (room temperature, the surface of the water, the material the pan is made of and its thickness).

However, there are two temperatures which are easy to attain in your kitchen. $100\,^\circ\mathrm C$ (don't need to explain this) and $0\,^\circ\mathrm C$ - for this, you can let ice cubes sit on the counter until they melt. Stir/mix the water/ice mixture and as long as they are some ice cubes left, you're guaranteed that it is at $0\,^\circ\mathrm C$.

Now the heat capacity of water stays almost constant if you go from $0\,^\circ\mathrm C$ to $100\,^\circ\mathrm C$, see for example this table - fifth column:
http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-thermal-properties-d_162.html

Informally speaking, this means that you need the same amount of energy to get a kilogram of water from $2\,^\circ\mathrm C$ to $3\,^\circ\mathrm C$ as you need to get it from $92\,^\circ\mathrm C$ to $93\,^\circ\mathrm C$.

Because of this property, you can mix $30\,\%$ of the $0\,^\circ\mathrm C$-water and $70\,\%$ of the $100\,^\circ\mathrm C$-water and you'll end up with a liquid that is at $70\,^\circ\mathrm C$, up to a small error.

For liquids that have a heat capacity that varies strongly with temperature, you can do the same thing but the calculation is more difficult.

Comment: Quite interesting answer; thanks Vibert.
In addition, with an accuracy of ±5°C to the boiling water, we get 70±3.5°C which is enough I guess.
Besides if I don't have ice with me, melting ice can be replaced by water from the fridge (at ~4°C), then _x_ becomes 68.75% which is quite close to 70%.

Comment: In practice I would use tap water of about 20 C.

Comment: If you know the temperature of your tap water, that's indeed much more useful advice!

Comment: Just remember that "ice water" means water at the same temperature as ice - don't use ice itself or you'll end up with cooler water because of the heat of fusion.

Comment: @Bernhard Tap water temperaute may depend on other factors (outside temp/sun, whether you just took a lot of water etc.), so just using tap water probably introduces quite some uncertainty. (Also, at my place, tap water is significantly colder tahn $20^\circ$.)

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- we have a volume of water $(v_1)$ at $100^{\circ} C$ (boiling water)
- we have a volume of water $(v_2)$ at $20^{\circ} C$ (tap water)
- we want a volume of water $(v_1+v_2)$ at $70^{\circ} C$
- the pot that will finally hold the $70^{\circ} C$ water will consume a negligible amount of energy from the water (generally a bad assumption. Might have to account for an addition $5^{\circ} C$ of temperature loss)

The energy $(Q)$ required to heat a body of water is given by:$$ Q = m \cdot c \cdot \Delta T$$

The mass of water is the same as volume. When mixed, volume $1$ of water will need to increase by $50^{\circ} C$ and volume $2$ of water will decrease by $30^{\circ} C$. Using our assumption of no energy loss we can setup the equation $$Q_1 = Q_2$$

$$v_1 \cdot c (\text{Water}) \cdot 50 = v_2 \cdot c (\text{Water}) \cdot 30$$

Our ratios of tap water to boiling water will be: $$\frac{v_1}{v_2} = \frac{3}{5}~.$$ e.g., $1~$ L of boiling water needs $600~$ml of tap water and will result in $1.6 ~$L of $70^{\circ} C$ water.

Answer (score -1):

You can start with water at $0^{\circ} C$, as suggested in Vibert's answer, measure the height of water in the container, and start heating the water. The density of water at $0^{\circ} C$ is $1 g \cdot cm^{-3}$, at $65^{\circ} C$ it is $0.981 g \cdot cm^{-3}$, at $70^{\circ} C$ it is $0.978 g \cdot cm^{-3}$. So if at $0^{\circ} C$ the height of water in the container is 10 cm, then the difference in heights of water between $65^{\circ} C$ and $70^{\circ} C$ will be approximately $0.3 mm$ and can be detected using a ruler (or a beam compass). Thermal expansion of a solid container is typically much less than that of water. I would think that not much water will evaporate when the water is heated from $0^{\circ} C$ to $70^{\circ} C$, but maybe this issue should be studied in more detail.

One could say that what I suggest uses the principle of an ordinary thermometer, but I am not sure this is worse than the calorimetric principle.

Comment: This method seems much to inaccurate to be useful in achieving 70°C. The effects of evaporation, expansion of the container and inaccuracy during the measurement (both from the meniscus and reading the values from the ruler) can influence the result at a scale that is difficult to take into account correctly.

Comment: @ahemmetter: The OP does not require a precise method. The calorimetric method has its share of problems, such as the need of mixing, weighing boiling water (it also requires taking into account evaporation), taking into account the temperature and heat capacity of the container. I agree that the method I suggest may be less precise, but I believe it is simpler.

Comment: Due to the small change in density compared to temperature, this seems like it really would not work well.  Getting a good 0.3 mm measurement would be difficult, and accounting for factors like evaporation would likely overshadow this by a large margin.  Evaporation rate increases with temperature, and unless the room is at 100% relative humidity, you would expect some evaporation before the heating even begins.